# How to make outer margin twice as the size of gutter in column grid?

Tags: css, margin, css-grid, grid-layout

How to make outer margin twice as the size of gutter in column grid? Usually I add same margin that i use on columns to my `.row` element. Is there any way to do it in more logical way? (because adding column margins to a row seems strange for me.
This is result that i want:

[image]

This is how i obtain it:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 8px
}

.col_1,
.col_2,
.col_3,
.col_4,
.col_5,
.col_6 {
  margin: 0 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.col_1 {
  width: calc(16.66667% - 16px)
}

.col_2 {
  width: calc(33.33333% - 16px)
}

.col_3 {
  width: calc(50% - 16px)
}

.col_4 {
  width: calc(66.66667% - 16px)
}

.col_5 {
  width: calc(83.33333% - 16px)
}

.col_6 {
  width: calc(100% - 16px)
}

*,
:after,
:before {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col_3">3</div>
  <div class="col_3">3</div>

  <div class="col_6">6</div>

  <div class="col_3">3</div>
  <div class="col_3">3</div>

  <div class="col_6">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: is it possible to get an image of what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `first-child` and the `last-child` pseudo-selectors, to reach the first child and the last child, respectively:

```
.row > div:first-child {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.row > div:last-child {
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```

Comment: It's not working in this case because i can place a lot of elements inside `.row`. For example if i have 4×col-6 inside my `.row` and these rules will not apply properly. My question is mostly about that.

Comment: @brachkoff first-child applies only for the first child, which is the first column. last-child only applies for the last child, which is the last column. Have you tried this?

Comment: As i said above: if sum of columns is bigger than maximum column number this will not work.

Comment: @brachkoff please create a Fiddle so we will be able to reproduce your exact problem.

Comment: @brachkoff I think I understand your problem now. You have more "columns" than the maximum width of the row, hence they are displayed in multiple rows. Is this the problem?